# Python/Pandas outer merge not including all relevant columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge the following 2 data frames in Pandas but the result isn't containing all the relevant columns:

L1aIn[0:5]
Filename  OrbitNumber OrbitMode

```
OrbitModeCounter  Year  Month  Day  L1aIn
0  oco2_L1aInDP_35863a_210329_B10206_210330111927.h5        35863        DP                a  2021      3   29      1
1  oco2_L1aInDP_35862a_210329_B10206_210330111935.h5        35862        DP                a  2021      3   29      1
2  oco2_L1aInDP_35861b_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        DP                b  2021      3   29      1
3  oco2_L1aInLP_35861a_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        LP                a  2021      3   29      1
4  oco2_L1aInSP_35861a_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        SP                a  2021      3   29      1

L2Std[0:5]  
                                          Filename  OrbitNumber OrbitMode OrbitModeCounter  Year  Month  Day  L2Std
0  oco2_L2StdGL_35861a_210329_B10206r_21042704283...        35861        GL                a  2021      3   29      1
1  oco2_L2StdXS_35860a_210329_B10206r_21042700342...        35860        XS                a  2021      3   29      1
2  oco2_L2StdND_35852a_210329_B10206r_21042622540...        35852        ND                a  2021      3   29      1
3  oco2_L2StdGL_35862a_210329_B10206r_21042622403...        35862        GL                a  2021      3   29      1
4  oco2_L2StdTG_35856a_210329_B10206r_21042622422...        35856        TG                a  2021      3   29      1

>>> df = L1aIn.copy(deep=True)
>>> df.merge(L2Std, how="outer", on=["OrbitNumber","OrbitMode","OrbitModeCounter"])

0  oco2_L1aInDP_35863a_210329_B10206_210330111927.h5        35863        DP                a  ...     NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
1  oco2_L1aInDP_35862a_210329_B10206_210330111935.h5        35862        DP                a  ...     NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
2  oco2_L1aInDP_35861b_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        DP                b  ...     NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
3  oco2_L1aInLP_35861a_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        LP                a  ...     NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
4  oco2_L1aInSP_35861a_210329_B10206_210330111934.h5        35861        SP                a  ...     NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
5                                                NaN        35861        GL                a  ...  2021.0      3.0   29.0    1.0
6                                                NaN        35860        XS                a  ...  2021.0      3.0   29.0    1.0
7                                                NaN        35852        ND                a  ...  2021.0      3.0   29.0    1.0
8                                                NaN        35862        GL                a  ...  2021.0      3.0   29.0    1.0
9                                                NaN        35856        TG                a  ...  2021.0      3.0   29.0    1.0

[10 rows x 13 columns]
>>> df.columns
Index(['Filename', 'OrbitNumber', 'OrbitMode', 'OrbitModeCounter', 'Year',
       'Month', 'Day', 'L1aIn'],
      dtype='object')
```

I want the resulting merged table to include both the "L1aIn" and "L2Std" columns but as you can see it doesn't and only picks up the original columns from L1aIn.

I'm also puzzled about why it seems to be returning a dataframe object rather than None.

A toy example works fine for me, but the real-life one does not.  What circumstances provoke this kind of behavior for merge?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you just need to a variable to the output of

```
merged_df = df.merge(L2Std, how="outer", on=["OrbitNumber","OrbitMode","OrbitModeCounter"])
print(merged_df.columns)
```